# Помогите сверстать сетку изображений

Tags: css, reactjs

Всем привет. Я делаю сайт на react и появилась необходимость определенным образом оформить группу изображений. Я пробовал делать при помощи material-ui ImageList. Сначала просто при помощи ImageListItem в ImageList, но там были проблемы с высотой контейнеров картинок и в итоге они распологались почти так, как надо, но с неправильной высотой(рисунок 2). Потом я решил разделить их на группы. Группа - ImageListItem элемент, в котором распологался ImageList элемент, в котором распологались ImageListItem элементы уже с картинками) В итоге, из этого тоже ничего не вышло. В этом случае вообще все было странно и далеко от того, что мне нужно. И, пока что, идей, как это сделать у меня нет.

[image: Рисунок 1]

```
const Drawings = ({grey}) => {
const drawings = [
    {img: drw1Img, cols: 2, rows: 6,},
    {img: drw2Img, cols: 4, rows: 4,},
    {img: drw3Img, cols: 6, rows: 4,},
    {img: drw4Img, cols: 2, rows: 4,},
    {img: drw5Img, cols: 4, rows: 5,},
    {img: drw6Img, cols: 3, rows: 5,},
    {img: drw7Img, cols: 3, rows: 5,},
    {img: drw8Img, cols: 5, rows:8,},
    {img: drw9Img, cols: 3, rows: 4,},
    {img: drw10Img, cols: 3, rows: 4,},
    {img: drw11Img, cols: 4, rows: 8,},
]

return (
    <AppContainer withoutTitle grey={grey}>
        <AppContainerItem lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
            <ImageList rowHeight={50} cols={12}>
                {drawings.map(({img, cols, rows}) => {
                    return <ImageListItem key={img} cols={cols} rows={rows}>
                        <img src={img}/>
                    </ImageListItem>
                })}
            </ImageList>
        </AppContainerItem>
    </AppContainer>
);
};
```

[image: Рисунок 2]

```
const DrawingsGroup = ({children, groupCols, groupRows}) => {
return (
    <ImageListItem rows={groupRows || 9} cols={groupCols || 6}>
        <ImageList rowHeight={50} cols={2}>
            {children.map(({img, cols, rows}) => {
                return <ImageListItem key={img} cols={cols} rows={rows}>
                    <img src={img}/>
                </ImageListItem>
            })}
        </ImageList>
    </ImageListItem>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сам я стилями не смог приблизится к желаемому результату. Но, на мое счастье, смог найти библиотеку Masonry(react-masonry-css), которая сделала хоть и не в точности то, что мне надо, но более менее приемлемо + ее можно довольно легко подстраивать под разные разрешения. Возможно, кому-то тоже пригодится.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]